# how to count clicks on tieh wordpress and google adwords

Tags: wordpress, events, google-ads-api

On my site

[www.intro.co.il](http://www.intro.co.il)

it's on maintenance but there is a catalog to download.

I need your with which code i need to put on my wordpress site so i can know the amount of click on the download catalog button in my google analytics account
I have tried the call center support and they told me to try here.

thanks a lot!

Answer (score -1):

Easiest (not necessarily most elegant) solution is just to track an Analytics event in the `onclick` handler of your button.

Something along the lines of

```
<button onclick="ga('send', 'event', 'Catalog', 'Download')">
```

This will let you see the number of clicks on that button in the Events view in Google Analytics.